# Using Neo4j and MongoDB together in a CPython framework

Tags: django, mongodb, neo4j

Well, here is my problem, I'll make an e-commerce project for my thesis, I'll make it using Django, and I wanna use NoSql solution, since I'll imagine that this e-commerce website will grow (...) the idea of that website is a social-e-commerce without money transactions, I'll use two solutions: MongoDB to store users information (since it's a schema-free) and Neo4j to make relations between users.

Ok, maybe someone will say: why not using Neo4j to handle everything since Neo4j is also a schema-free, but because it's Django, so I said that something that is a C-program will be better and faster for the web application than a 100% Java solution (when dealing with C-Django), I'll use CPython and not Jython, and I've installed JPype, so I imagine that calling Java from Python is something that will take time?

So my question is:

- is it better to use that solution: _id123456789012 is a (friend/best client/best seller...) with _id122234567890 as you can see the _id is generated from mongodb (the harder work) but only the relations are made using neo4j, so all the 80% of the work is done from mongoDB, or do i make everything with one of them: neo4j or mongo?
- second, if the solution of using both, how about scaling? from the graph that speaks about NoSql it seems that Neo4j is the latest in Scaling in size (while the best in Scaling in complexity) so will there a problem of "synchronizing"?

Comment: I think that your assumptions — that calling Java from Python will be slow, that a “C program” is faster than a “Java program”, and that any speed difference between Neo4j and MongoDB will be significant — are **dangerously misguided**. First, your Python program will be communicating with *both* databases via sockets, so it *doesn't matter* what language they are written in. Second, it's true that C *can be* faster than Java, but it's not *necessarily* faster.

Comment: Third, I would encourage you to do a quick prototype and benchmark it against both databases (and, personally, I would throw in a benchmark against a relational database too). Then, once you have *actual data*, you can make decisions about speed. I suggest the relational database because [using a NoSQL database can be a premature optimization](http://blog.codekills.net/2010/07/18/thoughts-on-postrelational-databases).

Comment: @DavidWolever thank you for the answer, but the problem is that it will not use the neo4j in a "heavy way" but only for "relations", so if there is an equivalent on MongoDB i'll avoid the neo4j solution?
and then, about sppeds, i speaked about django and python, and using cpython with java code will use an intermidiate tool JPype, si i guss that it will slow the operations?

Comment: abdel: I've never used JPype, so I can't say. Why don't you simply profile it and find out? Once you've got all the tools installed, that would take about 15 seconds with `ipython` and the `%timeit` magic function (ex, `%timeit neo4j.some_func()`, `%timeit mongo.some_func()`).

Comment: And, no, Mongo doesn't natively support the graph operations that Neo4J does… But using two separate datastores will almost certainly be more complex than using one, so if I were you I would profile all of: a relational database alone (ex, Postgres), Neo4J alone (ie, using it for 100% of your data) and the hybrid Neo4J + Mongo approach.

Comment: heu.......but about the relational DB, i've tried to avoid it at maximum, the thesis is something that am trying to experience with the new technologies, i want to show to teachers that there is also the NoSql world that must be used in third world country like Algeria, here the bandwidth is not as bigger as that used in Europe/USA, so this is why i've tried to make some "test case", and because NoSql is not "Swiss Knife" so i've said that using the two technologies will be better, but the problem i've found is the difference in language (Neo4j in JAVA and Mongo in C...)

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why the language matters. Unless you want to embed the database (hint: if you're worried about scalability, you don't) you'll be communicating with it over a socket, using a language-agnostic serialization format (IIRC Neo4J speaks JSON?).

Comment: Additionally, as I explain in the blog post above, NoSQL databases are (usually) an *optimization* … But if you're targeting an environment where *bandwidth* is the performance bottleneck, trying to optimize the database doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Anyway, nonrelational databases are an interesting field, so don't let this discourage you from both learning and teaching them. Just, please, make sure your decisions are based on *scientific fact* (ex, benchmarks) instead of *superstition* (ex, “C is faster than Java” or “a relational database is too slow”).

Comment: but the problem, is that (from what i've understood) when a language is used, for example neo4j, it's a java thing, so before it will speaks RESTful it must first compile the java code? and MongoDB will speak C, so i've said that there will not be some synchronisation, in Python there is directly a Neo4j embeeded and to talks to it, it will use JPype to convert the Python to Java, so i've said it will make some problems while synchronizing? but, dident know about sockets till now :) thank you again :)

Comment: Java is a JIT'd language, so every Java application will go through a “warmup” phase. Is that what you mean? And Mongo does not “speak C”. It is written in C++, but communicates over BSON, binary JSON.

Comment: ahhh!!! now i understand well how that "thing" worl :)
thank you again!!! now everything become clear! thank you again, now, how do i make your answer "the right one?" can you please it make an answer to mark that question as "replied"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the question has been answered in the comments, so I'm providing this answer to allow the question to show up as being answered.